# Convert hex stream to GIF

Tags: c++, c, perl, hex, gif

How do I create a .gif file from the following HEX stream:

0d 0a 0d 0a 47 49 46 38 39 61 01 00 01 00 80 ff 00 ff ff ff 00 00 00 2c 00 00 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 02 02 44 01 00 3b

3b is the GIF file terminator

I'm trying to do it following the guide at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format#Example_GIF_file

I'd like to implement this in either Perl or C/C++. Any language will do though.

Many thanks in advance,

---

Thanks guys for all the replies. I removed the leading '0d 0a 0d 0a'...

Here's what I have sofar:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(IN,"<test.txt");
open(OUT,">test.gif");

my @lines=<IN>;

foreach my $line (@lines){
        $line=~s/\n//g;
        my @bytes=split(/ /,$line);
        foreach my $byte (@bytes){
                print OUT $byte;
        }
}
close(OUT);
close(IN);
```

Comment: Um, you write the bytes to a file? Sorry, but I don't see the problem, perhaps because you didn't really ask a question.

Comment: How exactly should the hex stream be turned into a GIF? Simplest solution seems like entering it in MS Paint and saving it as a .gif :P

Comment: Look up "File I/O" in whatever language piques your interest. Open a file, write the bytes, close the file. Done.

Comment: Just insert `chr(i) foreach my $i (@image);` and same in C or C++.

Comment: By the way... you probably want to skip the leading 0d 0a 0d 0a

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it in the shell, using [GNU `echo`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/echo-invocation.html):

```
$ /bin/echo -n -e "\x47\x49\x46\x38\x39\x61\x01\x00\x01\x00\x80\xff\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x2c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02\x02\x44\x01\x00\x3b" > foo.gif

$ identify foo.gif
foo.gif GIF 1x1 1x1+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 2c 36B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

You can also use the [`xxd`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794902/whats-the-opposite-of-od1) command which will "make a hexdump or do the reverse".  Annoyingly, however, it seems very picky about the input format.  Here's an example using `xxd`:

```
$ cat > mygif.hex <<END
0000000: 4749 4638 3961 0100 0100 80ff 00ff ffff
0000010: 0000 002c 0000 0000 0100 0100 0002 0244
0000020: 0100 3b0a
END

$ xxd -r < mygif.hex > mygif.gif
```

`gvim` has an interface to `xxd`.  Use the "Tools → Convert To Hex" menu option (keyboard: `:%!xxd`) and then "Tools → Convert Back" (`:%!xxd -r`).

EMACS also has a built-in hex editor, which is accessed by `M-x hexl-mode` (see [Editing Binary Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Editing-Binary-Files.html) in the manual).  It's also a little bit annoying, because you have to type `C-M-x` (i.e. Ctrl-Meta-X) before entering a character by its hex code:

[image: EMACS hexl-mode]

Of course, it is very easy to write a simple C program to do the conversion:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  unsigned int c;
  while (1 == scanf("%x", &c))
    putchar(c);
  return 0;
}
```

usage:

```
$ gcc -Wall unhexify.c -o unhexify
$ echo  "47 49 46 38 39 61 01 00 01 00 80 ff 
         00 ff ff ff 00 00 00 2c 00 00 00 00 
         01 00 01 00 00 02 02 44 01 00 3b" | ./unhexify > mygif.gif
```

Also: [many answers here in this code golf question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795027/code-golf-hex-to-raw-binary-conversion).

Comment: +1 I didn't know Emacs has the hex mode capability.  Thanks for showing it.

Answer (score 5):

- Open a new file for writing (in binary mode) with the `.gif` extension.
- Read each pair of hex characters.
- Convert the hex to a byte (char) value.
- Write the byte to the opened file.
- When finished, close the file.

If the hex data represents a GIF image, the file should contain it.

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -ne'
   BEGIN { binmode STDOUT }
   s/\s//g;
   print pack "H*", $_;
' file.hex > file.gif
```

Perl 5.14:

```
perl -ne'
   BEGIN { binmode STDOUT }
   print pack "H*", s/\s//gr;
' file.hex > file.gif
```

(`-n` and `print` can be replaced with `-p` and `$_ =` if you want to golf (shorten the length of the program.)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to read the documentation for [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) (or [`hex`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/hex.html)) and [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html).  You may also find the [`perlio`](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html) documentation useful for creating a raw file handle (so `perl` doesn't try to help you with things like encodings or line endings).